# JMeter (CSS not apply in case of recording time )

Tags: css, jmeter

I need a help, I try to record a script of some application like http://in.musafir.com/ ,https://www.makemytrip.com/ etc but after recording started page is open but CSS not apply in that case I am unable to create script due to fields missing or disturbance.

I am not excluding CSS and other in JMeter proxy server page.

One another thing some application getting connection exception after used ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA (its apply in the case show the message) .

This all testing is done in home environment & company environment. And both places has same issue.

Please update me the solution of this issues.

[image]

Comment: Can you be please more clear. Do you want to record CSS requests or skip them ?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter HTTPS script recorder gives you option to exclude certain URL requests based on their type. You can add or remove these URL patterns in your HTTPS Test Script Recorder.

JMeter recording template by default excludes css. So if you want to record CSS requests then simply remove css from this section. Check screenshot for details.

[image]

Regarding Root Certificate, if you are getting a message like below then it is normal and expected.

[image]

Please read JMeter Official documentation for more details [about HTTP Test Script Recorder.](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

Comment: @ashok Can you please share screenshot of your Test Script recorder?